# Maximum number of survivors in team

Tags: the-walking-dead-no-mans-land

In *The Walking Dead: No Man's Land*, on iOS platform, what is the maximum number of survivors that one can team up in one level?

I've unlocked one slot more from those available since the beginning for 100 gold but still can't have more than three members at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can tell it looks like you can eventually unlock up to 9 survivors TOTAL. When you buy a survivor slot, you are adding to how many survivors you can have total in your camp, not how many you can take on missions.

Some missions allow you to take up to three survivors - others only allow you to take one or two.

Why buy more survivor slots? So you have the option to heal up or train up some survivors while taking others on missions. Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add. I've got 11 survivor slots at the moment. It seems that as long as your willing to spend money on bundles or save enough gold you can gain more slots. I'm not sure how many slots there are total though